# GeneratedTypeProvider in F# 3.0 Sample Pack

Tags: f#, type-providers

I'm currently playing around with the [GeneratedTypeProvider](http://fsharp3sample.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#SampleProviders/GeneratedTypeProvider/GeneratedTypeProvider/Module1.fs) in the F# 3.0 Sample Pack, but I'm having some trouble with it.

Currently I have Copy & Pasted the complete Provider in a file in my own library project. The only difference right now is the namespace that the type provider is in.

I can compile the provider without any problems. Then I proceed and add the produced .dll to my test project, as I would do with erased types. But I can't use the generated type - instead autocompletion shows me a note saying (translated into english):

> The type "TPTestType" is needed, but not available. You need to add a reference to the assembly "tmp6AF4, Version=0.0.0.0, ...".

Code of my test project:

```
open System
type T = Samples.ShareInfo.TPTest. //here, autocompletion shows the <Note>

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Is there some project setting that is in the original project of the GeneratedTypeProvider that I'm missing (because I'm using my own project)? Something else I'm missing or misunderstanding?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are the assemblies that need to be referenced in your project in order to use Generated Type Provider. Please make certain your project references them as well:

FSharp.Core //Should already be referenced

System //Should already be referenced

System.Core

System.Numerics

Comment: Hi,

thanks for the answer, but all three libraries are already referenced. The problem is not connected to that.

[Image of my project explorer](http://s27.postimg.org/jx1ihdfdv/project_explorer.png)